# where to store global database connection parameters

Tags: perl, security, database-connection

Is there a convention for storing database connection parameters and other global settings in perl? similar to .NET's .config files?

Background: I've inherited a large perl-based application, which has a bunch of cgi scripts, and several background services, all of which have database hostnames, usernames and passwords hard-coded.  I'd like to find a single, secure place to store these, and also to stick to perl conventions if possible.  I've not much experience with perl, and google doesn't seem to lead me to a convention for this.

Comment: Take a look at `Config::` namespace at CPAN e.g., Config::Multi, Config::Settings, Config::IniFiles, etc http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Config%3A%3A&mode=module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I've got so far:

Create a file called `config.pl`.  Place it in a location accessible to all scripts, reducing permissions down the bare minimum required for all scripts to read it.

As per [this guide on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Including%20files):

Make the contents of config.pl a hash:

```
dbserver   => 'localhost',
db         => 'mydatabase',
user       => 'username',
password   => 'mysecretpassword',
```

Then in each script:

```
use strict;

# The old way....
#my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=mydatabase;host=localhost", "username", "mysecretpassword");

# The new way
my %config = do '/path/to/config.pl';    
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=".$config{db}.";host=".$config{dbserver}."", $config{user}, $config{password});
```